# Wait until every process finishes

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I am working on a Javascript simulator that runs in a web browser. It has a main loop:

```
do {
    updateVisualization(simulator);
    simulator.doStep();
} while (!reachedGoal(simulator));
```

And for every iteration, I need to run several workers that must be concurrently executed:

```
doStep = function() {
    ...
    for (every agent in the simulation) {
        var worker = new Worker('worker.js');
        worker.onmessage = function(event) {
            ...
        }
        worker.postMessage(...);
    }

    // Here is the problem
}
```

My question is: how could I wait for every worker to finish?

Comment: The idea of web workers is to have them execute in the background and than have handlers (= callbacks) execute when they finish. Having a while loop (which blocks the UI) defeats the whole purpose of web workers...

Comment: Are you creating a new set of workers for each iteration? Couldn't you re-use the same set of workers for all iterations?

Comment: I am migrating the simulator from C# to Javascript so probably it can be improved a lot. I'll try to re-use the workers, and I'm still thinking about how to remove the while loop that blocks the UI.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A suggestion:

```
doStep = function () {
    var i, worker;

    updateVisualization( simulator );    

    simulator.workers = []; // array of workers for this step

    for ( i = 0; i < agents.length; i++ ) {
        // set up new worker
        worker = new Worker( 'worker.js' );
        worker.onmessage = function ( e ) {
            var i;

            if ( e.data === 'finished' ) {
                this.finished = true;

                for ( i = 0; i < simulator.workers.length; i++ ) {
                    if ( !simulator.workers[i].finished ) {
                        return;
                    }
                }

                // survived for-loop = all workers finished
                if ( !reachedGoal( simulator ) ) { // another iteration?
                    simulator.doStep();    
                }
            }
        };
        worker.postMessage( 'doStep' );

        simulator.workers.push( worker ); // push worker into workers array
    }
};
```

So all the action happens in the `onmessage` callback of the workers. Every time a worker responds with a message, you inspect the `simulator.workers` array by checking if all workers have a `finished` property set to `true`. If that is the case, this means that all workers finished and you can move on (the "survived for-loop" part).

So basically, you instantiate all workers and then just wait for their responses... no loop required.

Comment: Great anwser, Šime. It helps a lot to see how to use the callback and avoid the while loop. I wish I could vote it twice.

Comment: @Guido Cool `:)`. I've added a textual explanation in case someone else doesn't understand the code fully.